# node js os.networkInterfaces() not returning any results when called through docker entrypoint on AWS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, docker, nodemon

I have node.js running inside a docker container.  When I start docker, it then calls a script that calls node.js (or nodemon) to start.

Inside that node.js one of the first things it does is look for it's IP via

```
var ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
```

But it doens't work all the time, for reasons that mystify me:

1. AWS+Docker+manualstart node = YES!
2. AWS+Docker+autostart nodemon= YES
3. AWS+Docker+autostart node = NO

as 1, and 3 use identical plain commands my best guess is that docker is starting it before the network has been started. So either I can have the init script start the network earlier or poll until something shows up. Does anybody know the linux command to start the network set the ip?

Answer (score 1):

I opted to just setInterval till the os.networkInterfaces returned a non-null value, it varies in time from 100ms to 500ms or so on a slower AWS micro instance.